# How to wire up redux-form bindings to the form's inputs

Tags: javascript, forms, reactjs, redux

[redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form) is a very compelling library for providing redux bindings for forms in a react application, which should be super-convenient. Unfortunately, using the library's own examples, I'm failing to actually bind anything, which is super in-convenient.

I'm attempting to make use of the sample code on the project site, and finding multiple obstacles, despite attempting to reproduce it faithfully. Where am I misinterpreting this API? Has the API shifted since the demo code was written? Am I missing some critical and obvious piece of redux knowledge?

**Problem 1**: the signature for the handleSubmit method should be `handleSubmit(data)`. But handleSubmit is currently receiving only the React syntheticEvent from the submit action, and no data. (In fact, using the example as-written was sending two separate events, seemingly because of the stacked `onSubmit` action on the form and the `onClick` on the button.) Where is that data supposed to be coming from, and why am I failing to pass it to the handler?

**Problem 2**: there's a critical `fields` object that must be defined on the form parent and supplied as prop to your form. Unfortunately, the shape of that `fields` object is not explained in the docs, nor its purpose, really. Is it essentially the initial 'state' object? A simple object container for redux-form to use at runtime for errors, etc? I've gotten it to stop erroring by matching the props on `fields` to the field names in `connectReduxForm`, but because the data isn't binding, I'm assuming it's not the right shape.

**Problem 3**: The fields are supposed to be auto-bound to handlers for `onBlur` and `onChange`, so that they update the store appropriately. That's never happening. (Which we can see thanks to the Redux dev-tools. However, `handleSubmit` is successfully dispatching the `initialize` action, which suggests the store, reducer, and other basic plumbing are all working.)

**Problem 4**: `validateContact` is firing once on init, but never again.

This is unfortunately too complex for a simple Fiddle, but the entire repo (it's just the basic ReduxStarterApp, plus this form POC) [is available here](https://github.com/xml/redux-forms-poc).

And, here is the outer component:

```
import React       from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import {initialize} from 'redux-form';

import ContactForm from '../components/simple-form/SimpleForm.js';

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  counter : state.counter
});
export class HomeView extends React.Component {
  static propTypes = {
    dispatch : React.PropTypes.func.isRequired,
    counter  : React.PropTypes.number
  }

  constructor () {
    super();
  }
  handleSubmit(event, data) {
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log(event); // this should be the data, but is an event
    console.log(data); // no data here, either...
    console.log('Submission received!', data);
    this.props.dispatch(initialize('contact', {})); // clear form: THIS works
    return false;
  }

  _increment () {
    this.props.dispatch({ type : 'COUNTER_INCREMENT' });
  }


  render () {
    const fields = {
      name: '',
      address: '',
      phone: ''
    };

    return (
      <div className='container text-center'>
        <h1>Welcome to the React Redux Starter Kit</h1>
        <h2>Sample Counter: {this.props.counter}</h2>
        <button className='btn btn-default'
                onClick={::this._increment}>
          Increment
        </button>
        <ContactForm handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)} fields={fields} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(HomeView);
```

And the inner form component:

```
import React, {Component, PropTypes} from 'react';
import {connectReduxForm} from 'redux-form';

function validateContact(data) {
  console.log("validating");
  console.log(data);
  const errors = {};
  if (!data.name) {
    errors.name = 'Required';
  }
  if (data.address && data.address.length > 50) {
    errors.address = 'Must be fewer than 50 characters';
  }
  if (!data.phone) {
    errors.phone = 'Required';
  } else if (!/\d{3}-\d{3}-\d{4}/.test(data.phone)) {
    errors.phone = 'Phone must match the form "999-999-9999"';
  }
  return errors;
}

class ContactForm extends Component {
  static propTypes = {
    fields: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
    handleSubmit: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }

  render() {
    const { fields: {name, address, phone}, handleSubmit } = this.props;
    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <label>Name</label>
        <input type="text" {...name}/>     {/* will pass value, onBlur and onChange */}
        {name.error && name.touched && <div>{name.error}</div>}

        <label>Address</label>
        <input type="text" {...address}/>  {/* will pass value, onBlur and onChange*/}
        {address.error && address.touched && <div>{address.error}</div>}

        <label>Phone</label>
        <input type="text" {...phone}/>    {/* will pass value, onBlur and onChange */}
        {phone.error && phone.touched && <div>{phone.error}</div>}

        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </form>
    );
  }
}

// apply connectReduxForm() and include synchronous validation
ContactForm = connectReduxForm({
  form: 'contact',                      // the name of your form and the key to
                                        // where your form's state will be mounted
  fields: ['name', 'address', 'phone'], // a list of all your fields in your form
  validate: validateContact             // a synchronous validation function
})(ContactForm);

// export the wrapped component
export default ContactForm;
```

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate question! I had the same difficulties and I find the redux-form documentation and examples intricate and incomplete. With your and @Jonny Buchanan's help I was able to proceed (Although I have a complicated data-structure and I'm not finished yet). Adding the [redux devtools extension](https://github.com/zalmoxisus/redux-devtools-extension) also helped a lot with debugging!

Answer (score 23, accepted):

`connectReduxForm` wraps your component with another component which handles passing in the `fields` and `handleSubmit` props, but you're blowing those away by passing them in yourself.

Try this instead (renamed the prop to `onSubmit`):

```
<ContactForm onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}/>
```

And in `ContactForm`, [pass your own submit handler to the `handleSubmit` function provided by redux-form](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form#-handlesubmit--function):

```
<form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.props.onSubmit)}>
```

I recommend using the [React developer tools](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/09/02/new-react-developer-tools.html) to get a better picture of what's going on - you'll see how redux-form wraps your component and [passes it a whole bunch of props, as documented in its README](https://github.com/erikras/redux-form#props-passed-into-your-decorated-component).

[image: redux-form composition in React developer tools]

Comment: Could you update the link? All links point to `redux-form` github home page now.

Answer (score 8):

Thanks to Jonny Buchanan, who covered the most important point: don't do as I did and automatically assume that if props are required in your component, you must need to provide them yourself. The whole point of the higher-order function that is `connectReduxForm` is to provide them in the wrapper component. Fixing that immediately gave me event-handlers, for everything except Submit.

The other critical oversight was here:

> NOTE – If you are not doing the connect()ing yourself (and it is
>   recommended that you do not, unless you have an advanced use case that
>   requires it), you must mount the reducer at *form*.

I didn't catch the point of that. But, the implementation is here:

```
import { createStore, combineReducers } from 'redux';
import { reducer as formReducer } from 'redux-form';
const reducers = {
  // ... your other reducers here ...
  form: formReducer           // <---- Mounted at 'form'
}
const reducer = combineReducers(reducers);
const store = createStore(reducer);
```

The formReducer can't be referenced at `formReducer`, but requires the syntax `form: formReducer`. This was the correction that properly enabled `handleSubmit`.